# Looking for best way for Android to get closest address via coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps, geo

I'm looking for the best way to find nearest full address using Latitude & Longitude in Android.

Currently, I'm using the following way

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 1);
```

But for most cases it returns Street name without house number.

I will be very appreciate for any open source suggestions. (Something like cloudmade or Yahoo PlaceFinder).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void GiveResult() {
        Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);

            if (myList != null && myList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = myList.get(0);
                result = address.getLocality();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Iterator<Address> it = myList.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {

                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                tv.setText("Data is" + it.next());

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It still empty 
[Address[addressLines=[0:"avenue Mira",1:"Karaganda",2:"Kazakhstan"],feature=бул. Мира,admin=Karagandinskaya oblast,sub-admin=Bukhar-Zhyrau district,locality=Karaganda,thoroughfare=bul. Mira,postalCode=null,countryCode=KZ,countryName=Kazkahstan,hasLatitude=true,latitude=49.8123049,hasLongitude=true,longitude=73.0823207,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]

Comment: But that's the result coming back from Google. Can't do anything about it if Google doesn't have a more precise adress than that.

Comment: I dont think anyone will be ahead of Google if you consider Geo-coding.